# Create adjusted age with PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm building a registration system with PHP and need to create a function that takes a date of birth (as a timestamp) and returns the age on (April 31). What I have now is:

```
<?php
function get_adj_age($dob)
{
    $age = (time()-$dob);
    $today = strtotime(date('F d', time()));
    $diff = ($cutoff - $today);
    $adj_age = floor(($age+$diff)/31556926);

    return $adj_age;
}
```

For some reason this is breaking my brain. Anyone mind checking me on this? Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the entire function? I doubt `return $adj_age;` does anything outside of the scope of a function (except raise an error when not in an included file).

Comment: $cutoff isn't defined anywhere, so it'll generate a warning and be treated as null/0, so $diff is just "negative $today". And how does Apr 31 involve this function? It's not used anywhere. Plus using 31556926 to reprsent 365.25 days. congrats for allowing for leap years, but boooooo for using such ugly math.

Comment: `$today` should just be return value of `time()` instead of `strtotime()` call.

Comment: That magic number (31556926) is breaking my brain!

Comment: @anubhava I think that's just a bad attempt at forcing "now" to be "today at midnight", e.g. stripping hours/minutes/seconds and leaving just "year month day" in the timestamp value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function adjustedAge($dob, $adjustTo = 'April 31') { // DOB can be of any format accepted by strtotime()
    return ((new DateTime($adjustTo.', '.date('Y')))->diff(new DateTime($dob)))->y;
}
```

Essentially what this does it create a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object for April 31st of the current year and then subtracts the date the person was born. This results in a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) from which the year is retrieved and returned.

Comment: @deceze Because it was the date the OP mentioned

Comment: @deceze: Because that is what the question asks for.

Comment: But you're not supposed to hardcode that now, are you? Or rather, I wouldn't take that part of the request so literally... :)

Answer (score -1):

It's fairly simple. First get the current time and store it in a variable. Then get the age in milliseconds (Taking into account that before 1969 timestamps are negative, thus the ternary operator). The age is now in milliseconds, so divide it by the number of milliseconds in a year (60*60*24*365)

```
function getAge($birth){
    $t = time();
    $age = ($birth < 0) ? ( $t + ($birth * -1) ) : $t - $birth;
    return floor($age/31536000);
}
```

To get the age on a specific date simply create a timestamp for the day needed instead of using the current time.

```
$t = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 31, 2012); // <-- April 31st, 2012
```

Comment: Why milliseconds? PHP's native timestamp is standard unix "seconds since jan 1 1970". Milliseconds is Javascript territory. As well, `$t + ($birth * -1)` is mathematically identical to `$t - $birth`. So your $age sets to the same value regardless of $birth's value. You've also forgotten to account for leap years.